# Illustrator - combine paths into one shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I created a design in Illustrator by drawing a series of paths with the pen tool. I then grouped, duplicated, and reflected, to make the shape symmetrical. I then added stroke width, and created a stroke outline. I intend to export it as an SVG, but I cannot figure out how to remove the internal geometry:

[image]

I have tried the pathfinder, but that didn't help. I essentially want to 'flatten it'. Blender is getting very, very confused by the internal geometry when I import the resulting SVG!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"didn't help" isn't very descriptive... what happened??? but anyway....

---

**Pathfinder Panel** (`Window > Pathfinder`) and click the `Unite` button.

Note the Pathfinder **Effect** *menu* item is **not** the same as using the *panel*. The menu applies a live *effect* which must then be expanded (there are other differences as well). The Panel applies the pathfinder operations directly to objects creating a flattened result by default.

Comment: Sorry, fair point, 'merge' did literally nothing visible, and the other options deleted most of the path. This answer worked, I had no idea that panel pathfinder and effect pathfinder were different.

Comment: Merge *should* have worked... assuming all those "blacks" are the same "black".. if they vary even slightly, then yeah Merge would have done little. The menu would have applied the effect, but since it's "Live" you'd still see the highlights for the individual objects. So when highlighted, it'll *look* as if it were separate objects, but when selected and moved, etc., it will operate like one object.